# Automated release note generation from subversion. MS Word/PDF (lLaTeX?) output

Tags: documentation, automation, release-management

Recently I've gotten sick and tired of writing release notes and I'm really starting to resent the amount of my work day I spend writing these effectively disposable documents.

Currently we write release notes for all deployments to all environments except dev environments (sys test/sys integration/uat/live). Release notes must be tailored to each environment and contain a list of bugs fixed in the new build, a list of the changed/modified/added/deleted files in the release repo (since last build), deployment instructions and ancillary into such as project description and new functionality added.

What I'd like at the very least is some sort of plugin for MS Word which will allow me to pull formatted details from subversion repos such as lists of changed files. I can't seem to find anything which will allow me to do this.

Additionally I'd like to be able to generate the bug fix list. We're currently using HP Quality Center (yes, I know) to track bugs and test cases and such. I was thinking of duplicating the QC effort into redmine and pulling bug descriptions from redmine based on ID's included in the svn commit log - I doubt there's any easy way to interface with Quality Center.

Sorry if the above is a bit of a ramble, anyone have any thoughts on how to minimise the burden of release documentation through automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the move to Redmine sooner rather than later.

It has excellent referencing/linking between version control commits and tickets, and a roadmap/release notes view which aggregates tickets and revision messages against product milestones which can be easily exported.